# How to call the serialization method from a Generic

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

Disk Cache with Generics 
I am a programmer who comes from JavaScript and PHP, and am developing an App on Flutter, and am having difficulty implementing a cache on the phone's internal storage.

I would like to understand and know if it is possible to create a Generic type class with serialization for JSON so that it can be stored on file.
I've done the Cache implementation in memory and it works fine, plus the implementation of Cache on Disk I'm having difficulty.

**Code for Memory cache**

```dart
class MemCache<T> extends Cache<T> {

  Duration cacheValidDuration = Duration(minutes: 30);
  DateTime lastFetchTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);
  RList<T> allRecords = RList<T>();

  //is updade cache
  bool isShouldRefresh() {
    return (null == allRecords ||
        allRecords.isEmpty ||
        null == lastFetchTime ||
        lastFetchTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(cacheValidDuration)));
  }

  @override
  Future<RList<T>> getAll() {
    return Future.value(allRecords);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> putAll(RList<T> objects) {
    allRecords.addAll(objects);
    lastFetchTime = DateTime.now();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> putAllAsync(Future<RList<T>> objects) async {
    allRecords = await objects;
  }


}
```

**Code for Disk Cache**
How to call the serialization method from a Generic

```dart
class DiskCache<T> extends Cache<T> {

  Duration cacheValidDuration = Duration(minutes: 30);
  DateTime lastFetchTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);
  RList<T> allRecords = RList<T>();

  //is update the cache 
  bool isShouldRefresh() {
    return (null == allRecords ||
        allRecords.isEmpty ||
        null == lastFetchTime ||
        lastFetchTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(cacheValidDuration)));
  }

  @override
  Future<RList<T>> getAll() async {
    await _readFromDisk();
    return Future.value(allRecords);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> putAll(RList<T> objects) async {
    allRecords.addAll(objects);
    lastFetchTime = DateTime.now();
    await _writeToDisk();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> putAllAsync(Future<RList<T>> objects) async {
    allRecords = await objects;
    lastFetchTime = DateTime.now();
    await _writeToDisk();
  }

  //parth
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  //file pointer
  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/allRecords.json');
  }

  //write to file
  Future<File> _writeToDisk() async {
    try {
      File recordedFile;
      if (allRecords != null) {
        var map = allRecords.map((c) {
          var item = c as ISerialization;
          return item.toJson();
        }).toList();

        var jsonString = jsonEncode(map);

        final file = await _localFile;
        // Write the file
        recordedFile = await file.writeAsString(jsonString);
      }
      return recordedFile;
    } catch (e) {
      print("writeToDisk: " + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
// ************************** issues on this part ******************
  Future<RList<T>> _readFromDisk() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      var parsedJson = jsonDecode(contents);

      if (allRecords == null) {
        allRecords = RList<T>();
      }
      allRecords.clear();

      for (var item in parsedJson) {
       // ************************** issues on this part ******************
        print(T.fromMap(item));
        allRecords.add(T.fromMap(item));
      }

      return allRecords;
    } catch (e) {
      print("readFromDisk: " + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Error: The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the class 'Type'.
 - 'Type' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromMap'.
        allRecords.add(T.fromMap(item));
                         ^^^^^^^

Comment: The method `fromMap` is an instance method. You can invoke this method only via the instance. The variable`T` also an instance. But it is instance of type `Type`.  It is not an instance or type `T`. First you should instantiate an instance of type `T`. Only after that you can access instance methods.